# custom Matplotlib scaling: Log(Ln(x))

Tags: plot, matplotlib, scale

I have the following situation: I have a plot with two y axis, the left one is of logarithmic scale and shows the quantitiy `y(x)`. `x` is linear on the x axis. On the second `y` axis, I want an additional natural logarithmic scale of the same values that are plotted on the first axis. So imagine I have the following ticks on the first `y` axis:

```
10^0       10^1       10^2
```

Then on the second `y` axis I would have a scale between

```
exp(10^0)  exp(10^1)  exp(10^2)
```

Using the code from this [example](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/api/fahrenheit_celcius_scales.html), I managed to set the limits of the second axis correctly. However, since the scale is different from logarithmic, the values in between are placed in the wrong way. Since `exp(10^2)` is extremely large, the ticks for `exp(10^1)` and `exp(10^0)` lie very close to each other at the bottom of the axis, while `10^1` is located exactly in the middle on the first y axis.

I figured that I could use a custom scale, but the examples are quite complicated and I thought there might be an easier way to do this. If not, I could still label the ticks myself manually, which is a quite dirty solution.

---

An example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2

from numpy import arange, exp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = plt.twinx()
ax1.set_yscale("log")
ax2.set_yscale("log")
ax1.grid(True)

# the conversion
def time(energy):
    return exp(energy)

# the callback to adjust the limits
def update_ax2(ax1):
   y1, y2 = ax1.get_ylim()
   ax2.set_ylim(time(y1), time(y2))
   ax2.figure.canvas.draw()
ax1.callbacks.connect("ylim_changed", update_ax2)

# plot some function
xvals = arange(0,4,0.1)
ax1.plot(xvals, exp(xvals), '-')

plt.show()
```

The resulting picture looks like this:

[image: The plot]

As you can see, the upper and lower axis limits match on the left and right scale, while the mid point doesn't, since the scaling is different on the right axis. Though I ended up putting the desired ticks manually for my picture, it would be nice if there was a simple solution for this problem. The conversion function is just `exp(y)`, when `y` is the tick on the left axis.

Comment: Can you post the sample code and figure.

Comment: I could not think of any other way than custom scale

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try and use FuncFormatter:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter

...

def ticks2(y, pos):
    return '%1.1e' % exp(y)

xvals = arange(0,4,0.1)
ax1.plot(xvals, exp(xvals), '-')
ax2.set_ylim(ax1.get_ylim())
ax2.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(ticks2))

plt.show()
```

Note that I more or less bypass your callback, with the line `ax2.set_ylim(ax1.get_ylim())`.
The above doesn't not seem to much of a kludge, but it does have the disadvantage that the spacing of the tick numbers isn't that nice (as you will see if you try this).

Then again, I'm still trying to figure out what you are trying to plot on the second y-axis, and whether it is really useful to display it this way (I see time and energy mentioned, so energy is an exponential function of something, and time increases exponentially with energy?). But that's another question.